# the post-commit hook failed can connect url

Tags: svn

What should I do ?
My server is win2008.I want to make a hook,the document "post-commit.cmd" can work when doule cllik it,but can't work when i commit at client.it can't connect url.but the url can work in chorme.

```
Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:  
Error: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://my ip/svn/chat'  
Error: svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted

@echo off
SET REPOS=%1
SET USER=%2
SET SVN="C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe"
SET DIR="D:\web\ultraman\chat"
(call %SVN% update %DIR% --username wbj --password wbj666 --non-interactive)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the server certificate. Contact an administrator for assistance:

> Error: svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed:
>   issuer is not trusted

To suppress the warning, add [`--trust-server-cert`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.trust_server_cert) command-line option to the `svn.exe` .